# mongodb script for delete document in two collections

Tags: mongodb, nosql

How can i write a nested query involve two collection.

For instance I have student and assignment collections.

```
Student:

{
"_id":"556",
"name":"sam",
"assignment":[{"2","3"}]
}

Assignment:
{
"_id":"2",
"name":"math"
}

{
"_id":"3",
"name":"english"
}
```

How can i write a script when student id = 556 delete, the relevant assignment documents also get delete

This is how the collection looks in json format,

```
    {
    "_id" : "123",  
    "media" : [ 
        "33", 
        "44"
    ],
    "sectionId" : "dd",
    "courseId" : "string",
    "startDate" : "string",
    "endDate" : "string",
    "title" : "string"
}
```

So i want to get the media ids and use it with a $in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before deleting the student, get the assignment ids in a list and then use that array as a query for removing documents in the assignment collection. Something
like the following operation:

```
// Get assignmentIds = ["2", "3"]
var assignmentIds = db.student.findOne({"_id": "556"}).assignment; 
// Delete student 
db.student.remove({"_id": "556"});
// Delete associated assignments
db.assignment.remove({ "_id": { "$in": assignmentIds } });
```

---

Supposing you have a criteria that returns multiple documents and would require querying using **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** instead of **[`findOne()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/#db.collection.findOne)** then you need to [iterate the cursor](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) returned by the **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** function, load the assignemnt id's from each document into a single array, then use that in your remove operation.

Using the same example above, you could use the **[`forEach(`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/)**) cursor method to iterate the cursor, concatenate the assignement ids array using native JavaScript's **[`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)** method. Consider the following example:

```
// Get assignment ids
var assignmentIds = [];
db.student.find({"firstName": "Jane"}).forEach(function (doc){
    assignmentIds = assignmentIds.concat(doc.assignment);
});

// print the array
printjson(assignmentIds);

// Delete students
db.student.remove({"firstName": "Jane"});

// Delete associated assignments
db.assignment.remove({ "_id": { "$in": assignmentIds } });
```

Comment: @Harshana That's not even a valid BSON document. Can you please edit your question to include the actual document returned with the `db.student.findOne({"_id": "556"})` query because `{"2","3"}` is not even a valid object.